# Oauth2 and YouTube - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I've been working on this unsuccessfully for a long time now.  The YouTube developer examples seem straightforward enough, but I always meet the same two errors:

Access is Denied (when running on IIS)

Or

redirect_uri_mismatch (When running in Visual Studio)

This is the code that always fails for me:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );
  }
```

I have:
- Updated the clients_secret and used it with the Javascript version, so I'm fairly sure that isn't the issue
- Tried to create a custom FileDataStore to add as another parameter

Here is more detail to the Access Denied error I get when debugging.  It appears as soon as I get to the "credential" line.

> at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\ApiaryDotnet\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at _Default.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Michael\documents\visual studio 2015\websites\website1\Default.aspx.cs:line 46

And this is what shows up in the properties for the credential right before it errors out:

> ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   WriteTimeout = 'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  int {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: What does Postman say when you try to connect with your data?

Comment: Where are you getting the exception, and what are you trying to do with the result?

Comment: I added some of the errors, I haven't tried postman before but I'll give that a try and keep looking into the errors and tell you if I find anything new.

Comment: Alright so I was able to try Postman (handy) and it does validate my request and provides me with a token.